# Encode a big file using base64

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode/decode a file that is several MBs or sometimes GBs in base64 encoding however some pieces of data gets encoded/decoded in a wrong way which results in strange characters like: � �̴.

I'm reading the file chunk by chunk encoding and saving each individually (Probably that's the problem however i cannot figure it out).

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
<?php

function encode_file($Ifilename, $Efilename){
    $handle = fopen($Ifilename, 'rb');
    $outHandle = fopen($Efilename, 'wb');
    $bufferSize = 8151;
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fread($handle, $bufferSize);
        $ebuffer = base64_encode($buffer);
        fwrite($outHandle, $ebuffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($outHandle);
}

function decode_file($Ifilename, $Efilename){
    $handle = fopen($Ifilename, 'rb');
    $outHandle = fopen($Efilename, 'wb');
    $bufferSize = 8151;
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fread($handle, $bufferSize);
        $dbuffer = base64_decode($buffer);
        fwrite($outHandle, $dbuffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($outHandle);
}

encode_file('input.txt', 'out.bin');//Big text file ~4MBs

decode_file('out.bin', 'out.txt');
```

Comment: _**[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) isn't encryption**_. It's not even close. What's your goal here?

Comment: I do know that, the goal is simply to decrease readability

Comment: Huh. I always thought that the goal was to transmit binary data in text form using a reduced character set.

Comment: Base64 doesn't decrease readability in any meaningful way. Anybody can base64 decode the data without a key or any special knowledge. If you're trying to obfuscate something this is a pretty ineffective approach.

Comment: Question: Why do you need to encrypt these files? (and don't just say for security, thats obvious), What are these files? how are they being stored? Why can the public access them?

Comment: base64_encode is not bit-by-bit operation, therefore your file is now corrupted.

Comment: I DO know that, I'm doing it to convert files to binary and decrease readability

Comment: It might decrease readability for some people but it won't help much if anyone really want to read your file. Also, this will increase the filesize quite with about one third so you are wasting quite a lot of space for this.

Comment: A base64 string is 1.333 times larger than its source (by design). So when decoding the base64, you don't want to do `$bufferSize = 8151;`, you want `$bufferSize = 10868;`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - nope. it's to transmit binary data in non-binary (ascii) format.

Comment: You are also taking your "sometimes GBs" sized files and increasing their size by 33%. Noone is going to try to "read" your 1GB+ files, and if they did, they would be able to very quickly identify it as base64 and decode it fairly easily. At best, you are reducing the ability by some tools like grep to search the file contents.

Comment: Why not just gzip the files? This will make them unreadable (to the average user who wants to just peek directly at the contents) and smaller (unlike base64) and easy to decompress without doing something fancy and hand-rolled.

Comment: My question here is how can i encode it, not why to encode it so please don't down vote for that. I do know base64 is not encryption, can be decoded by semi-advanced users and increases the file size 33% and still i want to use it

Comment: If you're using base64 to obfuscate your data you are making an objectively terrible decision. Unfortunately, we can't stop you from doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the whole [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) on base64, I found that every 3 characters encodes to 4 base64 characters, this is what was causing the file corruption.

The fix is to simply set the buffer to n when encoding, where n is a multiple of 3.

When decoding set the buffer to N, where N is a multiple of 4.

The working code:

```
<?php
function encode_file($Ifilename, $Efilename){
    $handle = fopen($Ifilename, 'rb');
    $outHandle = fopen($Efilename, 'wb');
    $bufferSize = 3 * 256;// 3 bytes of ASCII encodes to 4 bytes of base64
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fread($handle, $bufferSize);
        $ebuffer = base64_encode($buffer);
        fwrite($outHandle, $ebuffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($outHandle);
}

function decode_file($Ifilename, $Efilename){
    $handle = fopen($Ifilename, 'rb');
    $outHandle = fopen($Efilename, 'wb');
    $bufferSize = 4 * 256; // 4 bytes of base64 decodes to 3 bytes of ASCII
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fread($handle, $bufferSize);
        $dbuffer = base64_decode($buffer);
        fwrite($outHandle, $dbuffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($outHandle);
}

encode_file('input.txt', 'out.bin');

decode_file('out.bin', 'output.txt');
```

Comment: This still doesn't protect your data in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Who said anything about protecting ?

Comment: You did, in a content on the question: "I do know that, the goal is simply to decrease readability ". Base64 isn't about obfuscation. It's about encoding (usually binary) data using a limited character set for transmission over protocols that expect text.

Comment: Plus, you're still calling your functions `encrypt_file` and `decrypt_file`. That's a huge giveaway that you're trying to prevent people from reading the data. You've chosen the wrong tool. It's like trying to protect a novel by translating it into French.

Comment: Thank you, I think there is a confusion, my question is HOW to do it not WHY to do it.
If you have an answer i will be glad to discuss it with you else, I clearly stated that i do know what base64 is and what it does and still I want to use it.

Comment: I'm not confused. I just hate to see people refusing to learn.